# Makefile Creation in Java

Tags: java, build, terminal, makefile

I'm building a java program in Windows envoirment, but i need to be able to compile it in Linux envoirment. I'm currently having problems with the makefile:

the project folders are organized in this way:

```
project_folder
   library.jar
   src
      folder1
         a.java
         b.java
      folder2
         c.java
         d.java
      folder3
         e.java
```

The `e.java` file into `folder3` is in almost all the others `.java` files because it's the principal struct, and for every file i have the line

```
import folder3.e;
```

Wich Eclipse automatically generates when i use a structure from another class file. What the terminal tells me:

```
error: Package folder3 does not exist
```

this is the makefile

```
JFLAGS = -g -cp library.jar -sourcepath .
JC = javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = \
    src/folder1/a.java \
    src/folder1/b.java \
    src/folder2/c.java \
    src/folder2/d.java \
    src/folder3/e.java 

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
    find . -name "*.class" -type f -delete
```

It's my very first makefile for java and i think i'm wrongly including the references between classes, how i can solve this?

Thank you

**UPDATE**: @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam thank you for your detailed answer, now it's all clear and working!

Comment: Build systems such as [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/), [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) and [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) have been developed for Java because `make` wasn't deemed powerful enough. So if your project is going to grow, you probably want to switch to using one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-d .` to `JFLAGS` so the class files will be created with proper folder structure.

So your `JFLAGS` should be as follows.

```
JFLAGS = -g -cp .:library.jar -sourcepath . -d .
```

`-d` is the flag is used for destination folder in the above example its the current folder. You can use any destination but don't forget to add it to the classpath using `-cp`. By using `-d` you can keep the source folders clean, also cleaning will be easy, just remove the destination folder.

**Update**

The problem is the order of the Java files in `CLASSES` section. Since `folder3.e` class is referred in other classes it has to be at the beginning. It should be like the below one.

```
CLASSES = \
    src/folder3/e.java \
    src/folder1/a.java \
    src/folder1/b.java \
    src/folder2/c.java \
    src/folder2/d.java
```

Also you can keep the libraries in a separate folder then use `-cp libs\*` to add all the jars in the folder. It will be easy to maintain

So the folder structure will be

```
project_folder
   libs
      library.jar
   src
      folder1
         a.java
         b.java
      folder2
         c.java
         d.java
      folder3
         e.java
```

And the final Makefile will be

```
JFLAGS = -g -cp ".:libs/*"  -sourcepath . -d .
JC = javac


.SUFFIXES: .java .class

.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = \
    src/folder3/e.java \
    src/folder1/a.java \
    src/folder1/b.java \
    src/folder2/c.java \
    src/folder2/d.java 

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
    rm -r folder*
```

*Unrelated*

Why don't you use build tools [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) or [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/)?

Comment: Thank you, but adding the -d doesn't work, i get the same errors as before

Comment: If i use this: JFLAGS = -g -cp library.jar -sourcepath . -d . i get the same errors as before
If i use exactly your sting: JFLAGS = -g -cp .;library.jar -sourcepath . -d .  i get a different error, "javac: no source files" useage: ... ... /bin/sh: 1: library.jar: not found

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me a lot!